# Computing a Linear Transformation for a Matrix with respect to its basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm having a lot of difficulty with this specific problem. The professor has a solution that doesn't match up what I did. I was hoping someone could help me out.

Let $ A = \begin{bmatrix}1&3&-1\\2&0&5\\6&-2&4\end{bmatrix} $ be the matrix of $T: P_2 \to P_2$ with respect to the basis:

$B = \{v_1, v_2, v_3\} $ where

$v_1 = 3x + 3x^2$,

$v_2 = -1 + 3x + 2x^2$,

$v_3 = 3 + 7x + 2x^2$.

Find $T(v_1), T(v_2), T(v_3)$.

The answers I was given are:

$T(v_1) = 16 + 51x + 19x^2 $

$T(v_2) = -6 -5x + 5x^2$

$T(v_3) = 7 + 40x + 15x^2 $

I'm not getting the same results so I wasn't sure if I made a mistake, or if the solutions are incorrect. Any help appreciated!

What I tried doing was row-reducing A, and taking the column vectors corresponding to $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$ that contain a pivot, forming the spanning set. Then I tried to write $T(v_1)$, for example, as a linear combination of those vectors in the spanning set.

Comment: The solutions you've written look correct to me. What is your method for solving this kind of problem?

Comment: Your question’s title describes almost the exact opposite of what it is you’re asking about.

Comment: Sorry. I fixed the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the definition of a matrix for a transformation $T$, from a basis $B = (v_1, v_2, v_3)$ to itself. The definition is the matrix,
$$\big([Tv_1]_B ~ | ~ [Tv_2]_B ~ | ~ [Tv_3]_B \big)$$
where $[ \cdot ]_B$ represents taking the coordinate column vector with respect to $B$. So, reading the first column off this matrix tells us that,
$$[T(v_1)]_B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix} \iff T(v_1) = 1v_1 + 2v_2 + 6v_3.$$
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
T(v_1) &= (3x + 3x^2) + 2(-1 + 3x + 2x^2) + 6(3 + 7x + 2x^2) \\
&= 16 + 51x + 19x^2,
\end{align*}
as confirmed by the answers.

I don't really follow your method, so it's difficult for me to pinpoint where this misunderstanding comes from. I will say that often row-reducing a matrix preserves nothing but the nullspace of the underlying transformation (and other properties the follow thereform, such as the dimension of the range). Everything else can be changed by row-reduction.